# Datagrid not showing

Tags: c#, datagrid

My data grid is not showing up in my webpage at all.As in no table showing up.
I did follow this stack [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308276/populating-gridview-with-sql-data) and modified some of its code to suit mine,but it's not showing at all.

here is the code for my **class** which is triggered by the button.

```
   private void LoadDataGrid()
    {
        con.Open();

        cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT quotationID,quo_product
                             FROM JobQuotations
                             WHERE quo_custname = @custname", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custname",lblLoginName.Text);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        dt = new DataTable();
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }
```

and I have inserted it inside the **page_load**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
           LoadDataGrid();
        }
    }
```

here is the markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Show the grid markup. Step through your code, are there any errors?

Comment: @DGibbs wait I'm going to edit it.

Comment: Similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796348/datatable-dt-ds-tablesput-why-dt-is-null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `da.Fill(dt);`:

```
dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Let me try to add it.wait for a sec.